# Double check my knowledge: Unicode

Tags: c++

there is this method: SCardListReaders, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379793(v=vs.85).aspx

On MSDN there is an example.

After this call:

```
LPTSTR          pmszReaders = NULL;
LPTSTR          pReader;
lReturn = SCardListReaders(hSC,
                           NULL,
                           (LPTSTR)&pmszReaders,
                           &cch );
```

Such code is present which extracts strings from a *multi string* `pmszReaders` (multistring is terminated with double null characters).

```
pReader = pmszReaders;

while ( '\0' != *pReader )
{

     // Display the value.
     printf("Reader: %S\n", pReader );

     // Advance to the next value.
    pReader = pReader + wcslen((wchar_t *)pReader) + 1;
}
```

Just my question is. I think above code only works for **Unicode** right? If I disable Unicode support in my project, I think above code snippet will not correctly extract reader names? Isn't it?

For instance when I checked `wcslen` returns 22 when Unicode is set and 24 when Unicode is not set.

Comment: @delnan, Microsoft refers to UTF-16 as Unicode so it's hard to fault someone for using the same terminology. I do wish they had never done that.

Comment: @MarkRansom I know that (and am as unhappy about it as you are). But since I suspect OP does not know it yet, I figure it's good to draw attention to it.

Comment: @delnan: delnan thanks for response, although I didn't get quite what you meant. At least the question is resolved now, in the way I had asked.

Comment: @user2568508 I meant that what you and Microsoft call "Unicode" is only one specific Unicode encoding called UTF-16. As there are several other Unicode encodings, it's more accurate to say "UTF-16", and more importantly, it's absolutely vital to remember the limitations of UTF-16 if you want to support many of the languages Unicode is supposed to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the function to work in either a Unicode or MBCS build, use Microsoft specific `_tcslen` instead of `wcslen`.

If you want a compile time error if someone tries to use the function without Unicode, change `LPTSTR` to `LPWSTR`.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes that's what I understood, I would probably have to replace `wcslen` with `_tcslen` and also the cast `wchar_t*` to `TCHAR*` right? So my assumption was correct indeed above code only works for Unicode right?

Comment: @user2568508, if you do things correctly the cast to `wchar_t*` shouldn't be necessary. And yes, your original code with `wcslen` will only work on Unicode (UTF-16).

Comment: hmm.. ok I was bit surprised initially since it was sample from MSDN, but thanks anyway.